# How to Fix Eror Get Data In Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have a function to calculate similarity :

Code :

```php
function similarity(array $c, array $d)
{
    return array_sum(array_map(function ($v, $w) {
        return ($v * $w);
    }, $c, $d))
  /
  (
      array_sum(array_map(function ($w) {
          return ($w);
      }, $d))
  );
}
```

this is the script used to run the similarity function
Code :

```php
echo similarity(
  [1,3,3,3,3],
  [1,3,3,3,3]
);
```

how to replace the numbers 1,3,3,3,3, with existing data in the database ?

I tried using the following script but encountered a problem
My Code :

```php
$pengetahuan = App\Pengetahuan::all();
foreach($pengetahuan as $pa2) {
  echo $pa2->no_kasus;
  echo " : ";
  echo similarity(
    [
      foreach($pa2->getdetailpengetahuan as $dp) {
        $dp->nilai;
      }
    ],
    [1,3,3,3,3]
  );
  echo '<br><br>';
}
```

error message :

```
syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ']'
```

Please help me.

Comment: First of all stop duplication question. You already asked this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574092/how-to-fix-problem-laravel-syntax-error-unexpected-expecting

Also you cannot use `foreach` inside an array inside function argument [
      foreach($pa2->getdetailpengetahuan as $dp) {
        $dp->nilai;
      }
    ],`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `foreach` inside an `array` as function argument.

A better approach is you create a new array and then pass that as an argument to your function as below:

```
$dpData = []; // create a new array
foreach($pa2->getdetailpengetahuan as $dp) {
        $dpData[] = $dp->nilai; // assign you data to that array
}

echo similarity(
    $dpData, // pass that array here
    [1,3,3,3,3]
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call similarity function inside the foreach loop. Currently you are using foreach inside a function parameter/arg that is supposed to be just one array. You cannot pass foreach operations as parameters and hence the syntax error.

```
 foreach($pa2->getdetailpengetahuan as $dp) {
    echo similarity($dp->nilai, [1,3,..]);
  }
```